# in iOS 7 viewForHeaderInSection section is starting from 1 not from 0

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, ios7

I am dealing with `UITableView` in my project and this project is created in Xcode 4.5 and now I am working with Xcode 5, so my question is when I will run my project in iOS 6 , the `viewForHeaderInSection` method section is starting from 0 it's ok but If I will use iOS 7 to run `viewForHeaderInSection` section is starting from 1 not from 0

What is the problem is there any `UITableView` frame's problem or not

I can't understand what is going on

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Just encountered exactly the same issue, and the resolution turns out very simple.

Just implement this delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}
```

Form [Apple UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:), it mentioned

> Discussion
>
> The returned object can be a UILabel or UIImageView object, as well as a custom view. This method only works correctly when tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: is also implemented.

Comment: I was having the same problem until I realized the frame of my section header view had origin.y set to something other than zero.

Comment: Quite ridiculous that this is necessary even if you've set the table view's section header height property.

Comment: What about Auto Layout?

Comment: Yep, this is correct. Also check the UITableViewDelegate of your UITableView is not nil.

Comment: Thanks it helped me but does not make sense to override two methods for header.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3 Version:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}
```

Comment: Even after implement above method. I'm still facing same issue