# Why is my first section header in table not showing?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I can't figure out why the first section header isn't showing. The second and third show fine. I suspect it's because of the search bar.

I've tried offsetting the whole table like in [UISearchBar covered by section header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19010444) but I didn't notice it offset.

[image: hierarchy of elements]

[image: screenshot]

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // create the parent view that will hold header Label
    UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,-60,300,60)];

    // create the label object
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,60);
    UIColor* mainColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:47.0/255 green:168.0/255 blue:228.0/255 alpha:1.0f];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = mainColor;
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];

    headerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    if(section == 0)
        headerLabel.text = @"Friends";
    if(section == 1)
        headerLabel.text = @"Second Section Header";
    if(section == 2)
        headerLabel.text = @"Third Section Header";
        headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [customView addSubview:headerLabel];

   return customView;        
}

- (void) hideSearchBar
{
    self.feedTableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake( 0, self.searchBar.frame.size.height );
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //Number of rows it should expect should be based on the section
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [_imageDataArray objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
    return [array count];
}
```

Comment: Its working perfect for me are you changed any constraints or any?

Comment: No constraints. When i bring the searchbar out of / above the table in storyboard, then i can see the space for the header but it's blank...Is the searchbar hierachy ok like it is?

Comment: yap i set hierachy like this only

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It wasn't showing because i hadn't implemented **heightForHeaderInSection**
More details here:
[in iOS 7 viewForHeaderInSection section is starting from 1 not from 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932476/in-ios-7-viewforheaderinsection-section-is-starting-from-1-not-from-0)

Comment: I hate apple for these "bugs"... there was no problem before, and then, why only for first line...

Comment: And make sure the return type is CGFloat. Weird bugs if the return type is, for example, NSInteger.

Answer (score 0):

You got a bug in your code. Your header is there but it is setting at a `y = -60` with a height of 60.

Replace :

```
// create the parent view that will hold header Label
UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,-60,300,60)];
```

with This

```
// create the parent view that will hold header Label
UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,300,60)];
```

Here is the screen shot here

[image: Section 0]

[image: Section 0 and 1]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed a bug. But fixing it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Please re-do a Proof reading of your code. Just look at it if you are having any constraints set. In fact I am also using the same code & it is working fine. Please check the attached updated screen to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to explicitly assign delegates in code, even though delegates were already connected in the XIB file.

```
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
```